# How to return a reference to a nested Rust struct in WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, memory, rust, webassembly

I have 2 structs where I can access the `Parent` struct from JavaScript and create it with `new` method:

```
struct Child {
    foo: String,
}

impl Child {
    pub fn do_something(&self) {
        /* some stuff */
    }
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Parent {
    child: Child,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Parent {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            child: Child { foo: String::new() },
        }
    }

    pub fn child(&self) -> &Child {
        &self.child
    }
}
```

I cannot compile the code because of an error at the `child()` method:

```
cannot return a borrowed ref with #[wasm_bindgen]
```

Is there any way to get a pointer to `child` and access it from JavaScript? Why can Rust not return a borrowed reference to WebAssembly? Is this because JavaScript could modify its value and Rust couldn't guarantee immutability of the data?

Comment: I know nothing about webassembly, but I assume the borrow checker wouldn't allow passing a reference to javascript, because no guarantees that the reference lives long enough could be made. I imagine you could get past this with raw pointers.

Comment: You cannot return references to JavaScript, as JS knows nothing about lifetimes, and you could end up with a dangling reference. Most alternatives are either returning a raw pointer or an integer index into some global map.

Comment: In fact, when you call `Parent::new()`, under the hood, IIUIC, wasm_bindgen just adds it to a global map and returns an opaque index to your JS code. But since the object is _moved_ into the global map, there are no lifetimes issues.

Answer (score 0):

In WASM, Javascript is like kernel code.  It runs at the highest level of privilege and has free access to the entire memory space.  Some have mentioned that if Rust were to return an reference into JS, it could end up being a dangling pointer.  This would be bad, but it's not Rust's problem.  Like kernel code, it's Javascript's responsibility to be safe in that context.  The real problem is that there would be no way to ensure the JS didn't abuse an immutable reference in order to mutate data and cause memory corruption.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return reference from rust to javascript because of borrowing rules. Rust is very picky about memory and does not want any mutation to memory from outside. However, to get around this, we use raw operator.

you want to return `child`:

```
 pub fn child(&self) -> &Child {
        &self.child
    }
```

We use `raw operator` here. Borrowing rules do not apply to raw operator.

```
   pub fn child(&self) -> *const Child {
           // as_ptr is the reference to the child
            &self.child.as_ptr()
        }
```

We are telling the compiler that we are sure, we want a reference of this spot in the memory, we like to access the reference and we are not afraid of borrowing.

raw pointers are not safe. they are heavily used when u are creating this interoperation between different languages. Currently your javsacript code is pointing to the `child` reference but what if this reference gets mutated inside rust code, then javascript code would point to something else.